# How do I know if Onslaught is active

Tags: path-of-exile

I have a character with Perseverance Vanguard Belt which grants Onslaught buff when Fortify is active. My character has Fortify everytime he attacks via Fortify Support gem. However, unlike other buffs, Onslaught buff does not show up in the left corner of the screen. How do I know if the Onslaught buff is active when attacking? Is there a way to get the buff appear in the left corner of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Onslaught does normally show up in the corner with the other buffs, Perseverance Vanguard doesn't actually provide the Onslaught buff, but instead directly gives you the stat buffs associated with it. To verify this, Press C to open your character sheet and go to the Defence tab. At the bottom it will show your movement speed modifier. When you have Fortify, your movement speed modifier will increase by 20% due to the buff from Perseverance Vanguard.